# Does Wookie Common Lisp server process requests in parallel?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I have a Wookie-based app accepting requests behind nginx. The app works in general, but I'm running into some issues with parallel requests. For instance, when the app accepts a long-running request (R1) to generate a report from a dataset in the database (mongodb, via cl-mongo), it would appear unresponsive to any following request (R2) that comes in before the response to R1 starts being sent over the network.

The client reports an error in communicating with the server for R2, but after the server finishes with R1 and finally sends the reponse, it tries to process R2 (as evident from debugging output) -- performs proper routing etc (only too late).

Putting blackbird promises around the request processing routines didn't help (and was probably excessive anyway as Wookie is designed to be async).

So what's the proper way to handle this? I'm probably okay with clients waiting for a long time for their responses (via very long timeouts), but it would be much better to process short requests in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of the underlying libraries (libevent2, libuv) of cl-async, is to use IO wait time of one task (request) for CPU time of another task (request). So it is just a mechanism to not waste IO wait time. The only thing happening in parallel is IO and at most one task using the CPU at a time (per thread/process depending on implementation).

If your requests need on avarage `x` ms of CPU time, then as soon as you have `n` requests in parallel, where `n` is the number of cores, your `n+1`st requests has to wait at least `x` ms, regardless of whether you use a threaded or event based server.

You can of course spawn more server processes and use load balancing to make use of all available cores.

Comment: Are you saying cl-async is not inherently multithreaded, so in theory wrapping the execution of parallel requests into threads should solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, not inherently multithreaded, and yes up to a certain point. The longer our request processing takes (either due to cpu usage or blocking io) the more resources (cores) you have to throw at it, assuming a constant amount of requests per time served.
Another question, that might be worth investigating: Is your database IO blocking, or does cl-mongo use cl-async as well?

Comment: From what I can gather, cl-mongo doesn't use cl-async, but appears to be multithreaded.

Comment: Hi, author of Wookie here (sorry to weigh in this late). Wookie's specialty is going to be in handling IO. Accepting requests, calling APIs over HTTP/TCP, talking to databases, etc. If a good number of your requests require CPU-intensive tasks, you really might want to check out Hunchentoot. If only a few use CPU, you'll want to ship them to a thread pool (like lparallel) so they don't block the event loop/IO thread. Check out http://orthecreedence.github.io/cl-async/threading for more info!

Comment: andrew, thanks. I ended up going with a simple DIY thread queue for long-running requests, which works for now, so your suggestion is on point.